# How to properly generate a concat'd function name with defmacro?

Tags: elisp-macros, eval

I have a macro like this:

```lisp
(defmacro my-fun-generator (x)
  `(defun ,(intern (concat "fun-" x)) ()
     ,(concat "Print " x)
     (interactive)
     (print ,x)))
```

This works (found an example online):

```lisp
(dolist (str '("foo" "bar" "baz"))
  (eval `(my-fun-generator ,str)))
```

But this errors with `(wrong-type-argument sequencep str)` on the first `concat`:

```lisp
(dolist (str '("foo" "bar" "baz"))
  (my-fun-generator str))
```

Is it saying the `str` is not of type sequence? Wouldn't `str` be of type string? Is a string a sequence? Just, why doesn't the second version work?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(dolist (str '("foo" "bar" "baz"))
  (my-fun-generator str))
```

Yes, a string is a sequence, but the symbol `str` is not a string - it's a symbol (which is not a sequence).  What you want to pass to the macro is not `str` but the *value* of `str`. Instead, you're passing the symbol `str` to the macro.

*Macros do not evaluate their arguments*, by default.

That's why the example you copied *substitutes* the value of `str` for `str` in the sexp (list) `(my-fun-generator...)`, and it then evaluates the resulting sexp.

After the substitution, in the first loop iteration, the sexp to be `eval`d is the *list* `(my-fun-generator "foo")`.  It's because of that `eval` that `my-fun-generator` is then used as a macro - expanded and its result evaluated.